# Need some help with understanding existing CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I found this great website with different layout examples at http://matthewjamestaylor.com

And in particular this one: [link text](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-left-menu-pixels.htm)

(view source for full css and markup)

I am just learning css and couldn't find where can I change modify the width of margins (of the left and the middle columns)

Every value in this layout is connected to another, so if i change at one place it changes other places.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, check out CSSEdit. It's amazing.  http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First step: install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

There are three connected values you need to change: the `width` and `right` of the sidebar (`.col2`), and the `left` value of the middle column (`.colright`).

For example, try the following changes:

```
.colright { left: 300px; }

.col2 { right: 250px; }
```

This changes the sidebar's width, but not its text width (thus the text appears to have a larger margin).

Comment: can you please explain how Firebug helps here?

Comment: markiz: It lets you modify CSS properties on the fly and see the effect in realtime. It certainly helped *me* solve the dependencies to tackle your problem.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I couldn't have said that better myself.

Answer (score 3):

The one on the left is controlled by:

```
.leftmenu .col2 {
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    position:relative;
    right:185px;
}
```

**Note:** the `right` value is greater than width, which is what controls the left spacing of that column. You would also need to change the last value of the margin.

```
.leftmenu .col1 {
    margin:0 15px 0 215px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    right:100%;
}
```

and the 200px `left` figure here:

```
.leftmenu .colright {
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float:left;
    left:200px;
    position:relative;
    width:200%;
}
```

Notice the pattern? 15 pixels on the left then 170 pixels of content = 170 and 185. Add 15 pixels on the right, go to the next column and then add another 15 pixels and you're at 215 pixels.